# The Meaning of "Crank" in Scotts slang?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

On a train, earlier today I overheard one Scottish guy say to another: "There's nary a hold chap in that bunch of slordy, poofy freeks. All o' 'em is *crank* in the head, that's what I say".

I have heard him and also other people use this term from time to time, but I am still not quite sure what it means.

Comment: You knew what slordy meant?

Comment: You can deduce what he means by the context. Any time someone says "<blank> in the head" you can pretty much assume they are referring to their mental state.

Comment: Well, I guess, you could. But sometimes it is hard to come to a correct illation, especially if you have heard the word in question used a couple of times in a few different contexts and did not understand it. It doesn't always work like that. I mean, can you deduce what he meant by the word "slordy" for example (which is sort of fishermen slang)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not an obvious place to look for the definition of a sense, [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crank) has:

> **crank**
>
> English retains the literal sense of the ancient root, while German
>   and Dutch krank "sick," formerly "weak, small," is from a
>   figurative use. The 1825 supplement to Jamieson's Scottish dictionary
>   has crank "infirm, weak, etc."

Comment: Yeah, I think "sick" or "weak" kind of makes sense here. And as far as I understand "crank" is a derogatory term, and it is used mostly to disparage people. It seems to be very offensive. I have encountered it just a couple of times in a couple of decades in phrases like: "that crank fuck" or " come over here you crank bastard".

Comment: Remember that modern English usage may be rather or very different from archaic or dialect ones:  {[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crank)}   crank [adj]: of, relating to, or being a cranky or eccentric person ...  // [noun] 2 ... c: an annoyingly eccentric person; also :  one who is overly enthusiastic about a particular subject or activity
d:  a bad-tempered person :  grouch // The older Scottish usage (sick / weak) is unmarked for eccentricity / grouchiness, until coupled with 'in the head'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And a word with an interesting history. The OED makes connections between crank and crook.  The latter, curiously, is a common Australian expression for being 'sick' or 'unwell'.  Probably another case of British dialects being transferred to and kept in common use in the former British colonies.